# How to reset/delay .after in Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I want to delay .after every time a button is pressed. Like if timer is set for 10 seconds, so if left alone it will count for 10 seconds. 10, 9, 8, 6, 5. But if any button is pressed it will reset back to 10 seconds. 5 --> 10. I do not want the method that adding the time because it will create inconsistent time for the execution.

Example:

```
app.tk()
def close_app():
   app.destroy()

destroy_app = app.after(10000, close_app)

if (button == pressed):
   app.reset(destroy_app)
```

Comment: [`after()`](https://i.guim.co.uk/img/media/35826ff6a48d54013c19738c01911a9552a1385f/0_0_3500_2333/master/3500.jpg?width=1225&quality=85&auto=format&fit=max&s=f64e329502f05312af42101592a5a185) returns an "after identifier" which you can pass to .`after_cancel()` to prevent the callback from being called.

Comment: A little research would go a long way to answering this question.

Answer (score 1):

as martnieau mentioned:
instead of app_reset(destroy_app)

try

```
if (button == pressed):
   app.after_cancel(destroy_app)
   destroy_app = app.after(10000, close_app)
```